# Recursion : multiple instances of function for each element in for is not created

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

i have a recursion problem. 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-increasing-sequences-length-k-first-n-natural-numbers/
But i see recursive calls to functions is not happening.
what problem could be with the code below:

```
def wrapper(n,k):
    list=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list.append(str(i))

    print rec_seq(list,k,0,'')

def rec_seq(list,k,i,prefix):
    #base case
    if k==0:
        return prefix

    else:
        for c in list[i:None]:
            newPrefix=prefix+c
            return rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix)

if __name__=='__main__':
    wrapper (5,3)
```

output : 123

```
Expected output :
            1 2 3
            1 2 4
            1 2 5
            1 3 4
            1 3 5
            1 4 5
            2 3 4
            2 3 5
            2 4 5
            3 4 5
```

Comment: Although it isn't the problem this time, it's a very bad idea to use `list` as a variable, because you are overriding the binding for the python builtin of the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def wrapper(n,k):
    list=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list.append(str(i))

    rec_seq(list,k,0,'')

def rec_seq(list,k,i,prefix):
    #base case
    if k==0:
        print prefix
        return 

    else:
        for c in list[i:None]:
            if prefix=='':
                newPrefix=prefix+c
                rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix)
            else:
                if int(c)>int(prefix[-1]):
                    newPrefix=prefix+c
                    rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix)
        return    

if __name__=='__main__':
    wrapper (5,3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop, if you use `return`, only that singular value will ever be returned. In your case, here is what it looks like.

First call to `rec_seq`

```
for c in list[i:None]: #i=0, c='1'
    newPrefix=prefix+c #newPrefix = '' + '1'
    return rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix) #k-1 = 2, i+1 = 1
```

Second call

```
for c in list[i:None]: #i=1, c='2'
    newPrefix=prefix+c #newPrefix = '1' + '2'
    return rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix) #k-1 = 1, i+1 = 2
```

Third call

```
for c in list[i:None]: #i=2, c='3'
    newPrefix=prefix+c #newPrefix = '12' + '3'
    return rec_seq(list,k-1,i+1,newPrefix) #k-1 = 0, i+1 = 3
```

*Last* call

```
if k==0: #True
    return prefix #prefix = '123'
```

So going back up the chain, the Last call passes '123' to the third call, which passes it to the second call, all the way back up to the original call which returns `'123'`

Comment: ohh i see now. In loop 1 the return statement is preventing further loops to execute.
Now i placed return outside the for loop ist working now. cheers:)